# transformed of Laplace

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'+2y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}t, &0\leq t< 1\\0,&t\geq1\end{array}\right.;\hspace{5mm}y(0)=0$$
what I do not understand is, at the moment of applying the transformed,
$$\mathscr{L}\{t-t\mathscr{U}(t-1)\}$$
I do not understand how to determine Laplace's transformation of the previous result

Comment: Please include the actual question and more context

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+2y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}t, &0\leq t< 1\\0,&t\geq1\end{array}\right.;\hspace{5mm}y(0)=0$$
For $0 \le t\le 1$
$$y'+2y=t$$
$$(ye^{2t})'=te^{2t}$$
$$y=e^{-2t}\int te^{2t}dt$$
$$y=e^{-2t}(te^{2t}/2-e^{2t}/4 +K)$$
Since $y(0)=0 \to K=\dfrac 14$
$$\boxed{\text{ 1) }y(t)=\frac t2-\frac 14 +\frac {e^{-2t}}4}$$

For $t \ge 1$ :
$$y'+2t=0$$
$$(ye^{2t})'=0$$
$$y=K_2e^{-2t}$$
We must have from first equation we deduce the value of y(1):
$$\text{ 1) }y(t)=\frac t2-\frac 14 +\frac {e^{-2t}}4$$
 $$y(1)=\frac {e^{-2}+1}{4}$$ 
Then we deduce the value of the constante $K_2$:
$$ y=K_2e^{-2t} \to y(1)=K_2e^{-2} \to K_2=\frac {e^{2}+1}{4}$$
Therefore for $t \ge 1$
$$\boxed{y(t)=\left(\frac {e^{2}+1}{4}\right)e^{-2t}}$$

Comment: Excuse me, then the transformation using the unit jump is not necessary? and another question: where do you get the second condition, where it says:$$y(1)=\frac{e^{-2}+1}{4}$$

Comment: And if you want to use a jump like I would ... technically I like this way better ... but I want to learn how to use it, please

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker With Laplace transform look here the answer of John may help you a lot https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629225/solve-the-initial-value-problem-ode-with-discontinuous-coefficients/2629249#2629249

Comment: Thank you very much ... I liked the development here more ... and a question, is this "way" equivalent to taking the unitary transformation? and one more thing, I have the following transformation: $$\mathscr{L}\left\{te^{-t}\delta(t+1)\right\}$$ Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}t, &0\leq t< 1\\0,&t\geq1\end{array}\right.$. Then the DE becomes
$$ y'+2y=f(t) $$
and hence
$$ \mathscr{L}\{y'\}+2\mathscr{L}\{y\}=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}. \tag{1}$$
Note 
$$ \mathscr{L}\{y'\}=sY(s)-y(0),\mathscr{L}\{y\}=Y(s) $$
and
$$ \mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt=\int_0^1e^{-st}tdt=\frac{1-e^{-s}(1+s)}{s^2}. $$
So (1) becomes
$$ sY(s)-2Y(s)=\frac{1-e^{-s}(1+s)}{s^2} $$
and hence
$$ Y(s)=\frac{e^{-s}(e^s-s-1)}{s^2(s+2)}=\frac{1}{s^2(s+2)}-\frac{e^{-s}(s+1)}{s^2(s+2)}. $$
Note
$$ \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^2(s+2)}\right\}=\frac14(e^{-2t}+2t-1). $$
Let 
$$ G(s)=\frac{s+1}{s^2(s+2)} $$
and then $g(t)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{G(s)\}=\frac14(-e^{-2t}+2t+1)$ and
$$ \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-s}(s+1)}{s^2(s+2)}\right\}=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{e^{-s}G(s)\right\}=u(t-1)g(t-1)=\frac14u(t-1)(-e^{-2(t-1)}+2t-1) $$
Thus 
$$ y(t)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^2(s+2)}\right\}-\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-s}(s+1)}{s^2(s+2)}\right\}=\frac14(e^{-2t}+2t-1)-\frac14u(t-1)(-e^{-2(t-1)}+2t-1).$$